# Javascript: SetTimeout and ClearTimeout reset.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have this following session time javascript code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var time;
    var sessionTimeout = <%= Session.Timeout %>

    function DisplaySessionTimeout() {

       document.getElementById("<%= lblSessionTime.ClientID %>").innerText = sessionTimeout;
        sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;

        if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
            time = window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 1000);
        else {
            alert("Your current Session is over.");
        }
   }

    function cleartime() {
        clearTimeout(time);
        document.onmousemove = cleartime;
        document.onkeypress = cleartime;
    }
</script>
```

It's able to count down. But nothing happends when i move the mouse or pressing on key. I want it to reset the counter on mousemove and keypress. Can anyone spot the error?

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to reset the timer to its initial value, then you're going about it all wrong. I also recommend using `setInterval` for this rather than `setTimeout` (and passing it a function rather than a string):

```
var time,
    sessionTimeout = <%= Session.Timeout %>,
    remainingTime = sessionTimeout,
    intervalHandle,
    lastPos = [0, 0];

function displaySessionTimeout() {
   document.getElementById("<%= lblSessionTime.ClientID %>").innerText = remainingTime;
}

function updateTimer() {
    remainingTime -= 1;

    if (remainingTime >= 0) {
        displaySessionTimeout();
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        alert("Your current Session is over.");
    }
}

function resetTimer() {
    if (remainingTime >= 0 && (e.clientX !== lastPos[0] || e.clientY !== lastPos[1])) {
       lastPos = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
       remainingTime = sessionTimeout;
       displaySessionTimeout();
    }
}

intervalHandle = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
displaySessionTimeout();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZERB/

Comment: Well what it does, it only stops the counter, but it doesn't reset it. I want it to start again when the mouse is moved

Comment: Ok, you didn't explain that all in your question, but please see the updated code above.

Comment: it's still not working. When i run it, the counter is just staying on 20. Not counting down.

Comment: I am figuring out what clientX and Y does. Well this time its counting down, but the onmousemove and onkeypress is still not resetting the timer. Maybe it has something to do with those functions.

Answer (score 2):

You do realise you are calling cleartime recursively, right?
Also, you are not even calling cleartime.
PS also replace

```
window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 1000);
```

with

```
setTimeout(DisplaySessionTimeout, 1000);
```

Comment: Even if it were called, `cleartime` is never calling itself.  Where are you gettting the "recursively" from?

Comment: I think cleartime is being called automatically when i move the mouse or pres on any key